# Is using static methods to access an API a bad idea?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, static, static-methods

Say I have the following code in a class called `MPWidget`.

```
// Get list of widgets from server
+ (void) getWithSuccess:(void(^)(void))success failure:(void(^)(void))failure
{
    HttpClient *httpClient = [[HttpClient alloc] init];
    [httpClient GET:@"http://example.com/widgets.json" success:^(void) {
        NSLog(@"Great success!");
    } failure:^(void) {
        NSLog(@"Boo, fail!");
    }];
}
```

The method above would be invoked as follows:

```
[MPWidget getWithSuccess:^(...) failure:^(...)];
```

I'm using static methods for the simplicity of not having to instantiate an `MPWidget` if I want to get one (or more) from the network. However, I've just been reading that [static calls are bad for testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/). Is that the case for a network data fetching method? Or is this an edge case?

Answer (score 0):

Class methods are bad for testability only when they are maintain some sort of static state. Stateless class methods, on the other hand, provide a great means for sharing procedural logic among other methods, and are trivially testable. They provide the default choice for writing "helper methods" such as your `getWithSuccess:failure:`. There is absolutely nothing wrong with stateless class methods.

> [what if I want to] inject an alternative implementation of `getWithSuccess:failure`?

The story is different for methods "at the edges" of your system, which are responsible for exchanging information with other systems, accessing data, and producing other side effects. These are the methods that you often want to replace for testing - for example, to give your system a "canned" JSON message instead of hitting a server.

Although such methods could be stateless as far as your code is concerned, they are not entirely stateless, because they either change with the environment, or make changes to the environment. This "outside statefulness" makes these methods bad for testability.

Comment: Thanks for that reassurance. I agree, that method is super easy to test. Counter to that, I've read arguments about problems when other static methods that call `getWithSuccess:failure` can't (easily?) inject an alternative implementation of `getWithSuccess:failure`.

Comment: @MattPotts An ability to Inject a different implementation for something that sits on the border of your application is a different story. Let me edit to include that in the answer.